# How to use [ and ] characters at github workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a workflow in which I'm trying to add the commit SHA to the filename, it's a zip file that will be released

What I've tried: ("41e4ebe" will be used as the SHA example)

```
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:

- uses: actions/checkout@v1
- name: Zip Folder
  run: |
    cd __Release
    zip -r FunTuna\[${GITHUB_SHA::7}\].zip *
```

Expected filename:

```
FunTuna[41e4ebe].zip
```

Result:

```
FunTuna.41e4ebe.zip
```

Here's the entire workflow
https://github.com/israpps/Funtuna-Fork/blob/main/.github/workflows/repack-and-release.yml

Answer (score 1):

Note: in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66071364/how-to-use-and-characters-at-github-workflow/66072415#comment116836221_66072415), the [OP El_isra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14403190/el-isra) mentions:

> I have added an `ls` command after making the zip into the workflow.
>
> What I have done from the very beginning seems to be okay, maybe the upload artifact or the release step is modifying the filename.

---

You can try using [`format`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#format) from the [Context and expression syntax for GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions):

```
format( string, replaceValue0, replaceValue1, ..., replaceValueN)
```

In your case:

```
env:
    FNAME: ${{ format('FunTuna[{0}].zip', '${GITHUB_SHA::7}') }}
run: |
    cd __Release
    zip -r $FNAME *
```

See if `format` returns the proper name.
You can see an example of that [command format executed here](https://github.com/VonC/gtarsum/runs/1846851200?check_suite_focus=true), from this [`test.yml`](https://github.com/VonC/gtarsum/blob/master/.github/workflows/test.yml) workflow.

Comment: It didn't work.  It says: unexpected token '('

Comment: @El_isra I agree, the syntax was not correct. I have fixed it, and tested it. I have edited the answer accordingly, and added links to examples: can you review this answer and let me know if it is working better?

Comment: same as before: FunTuna.SHA.zip
you're testing this with echo, it works with echo, but it doesnt work in zip, i've already tested that

Comment: @El_isra OK: let's try with an environment variable, then; since `zip` can use them (as [in here](https://github.com/actions/upload-release-asset/issues/17)). Please see my edited answer.

Comment: in that example youre assingning "${{ format('FunTuna[{0}].zip', '${GITHUB_SHA::7}') }}" as the enviroment variable value

Comment: @El_isra You mean the environment variable does not include the computed value?

Comment: it passes ${{ format('FunTuna[{0}].zip', '${GITHUB_SHA::7}') }} as the enviroment variable, and since it includes ':' the workflow gives an error

" Artifact path is not valid: /FunTuna[${GITHUB_SHA::7}].zip. Contains character: ":". Invalid characters include: ",:,<,>,|,*,?."

Comment: i've added an ls command after making the zip into the workflow.
what i've done from the very begining seems to be okay, maybe the upload artifact or the release step is modifying the filename